# How to know the running Blazor MAUI platform at execution time

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, maui-blazor

I want use differents components of UI for MAUI Blazor APP when its running in differents SOs.
I meant, one custom component if its running on  Android and other if it's running in Windows
(due to well document webview bug when you try to use html selec in blazor maui for windows).
There is some way to do this?, #if flag not semmeed to be work and i m using display size until now, but should be a better way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.DeviceInfo` which contains `Platform` as a property.
So you can do for example:

```
@if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
{
     <select></select>
}
else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.UWP)
{
    <CustomSelect />         
}
else
{
            
}
```

Comment: no you dont need to inject anything, DeviceInfo is a static class from the namespace i wrote in the answer. DevicePlatform is a struct also coming from that namespace.
Try answer in english please, i'm not spanish, i managed to understand ur question just because italian is kinda similar :)

Comment: you are welcome. Could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the following NuGet package which adds a Blazor component that can detect browser types, browser versions, device types and lots of other useful user agent information's.

nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PSC.Blazor.Components.BrowserDetect/

GitHub: https://github.com/erossini/BlazorBrowserDetect